# How can I spawn an object where I clicked in a 3D space, but spawn it in a 2D location?

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, vector

I have a game where I have an object sat on a 3D plane and I want to click above it to drop an object.  Wherever I click I want the object to drop where I clicked on the Z-axis, but on a fixed position on the X and Y axis.

Please see the below image:
[image]

I am using the following code to do that, which I have attached to my long cube (the platform).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class clickBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject GameCube;
    Ray ray;
    RaycastHit hit;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {

            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
            {
                GameObject obj = Instantiate(GameCube, new Vector3(-75, 9, hit.point.z), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                Debug.Log(hit.point);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

`GameCube` refers to the GameObject of the smaller cube on top of the platform.

What seems to be happening, is that when the user clicks a block appears.  If the mouse is low down the screen on click then it appears where it should be.  If it is higher up the screen it appears off in one direction away from where it should be.

I believe this is because Unity is picking up the click way in the background, but I'm dropping the new cube in the foreground.  Because of this the Z coordinate is then quite a way off.  The further in the background I click the further off it is.

How can I have the cubes always appear in the correct position, above the platform?  I'm guessing this is a common requirement, but struggling to work out how to do it, or what to Google to find out more info.

Thanks

Comment: What collider is your raycast hitting? Do you actually want to snap your drop point to a particular collider, or just to a particular line/plane? If the latter, you don't need raycasts to do that.

Comment: I think the latter.  I'm beginning to wonder if I'm going about this all wrong, and should instead place an invisible vertical and very wide collider/plane where i want the items to drop from, and basically have that as a giant click event catcher.  What is the best method?

Comment: Definitely the latter actually. I just want my drop point to be along a single axis (z) of the mouse. FYI, Z-axis in this instance is left to right when moving objects in the editor, not back and forth in terms of depth. Not sure that matters any